# How get array length for dynamic array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

have you idea how get number rows questions array after all the data contained has been loaded from API. I need set totalRows for pagination table but

```
this.questions = this.questions.lenght
```

not working and return null.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            questions: [],
            fields: [
                { key: 'id', label: 'ID', sortable: true },
                { key: 'title', label: 'Title', sortable: true },
                { key: 'updated_at', label: 'Last update', sortable: true},
            ],
            totalRows: 13,
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 5,
            pageOptions: [5, 10, 15]
        }
    },
    components: {},
    created() {
        axios.get('/api/question')
        .then(res => this.questions = res.data.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    },
}
```

I additionally add what returns mine API

```
questions:Array[10]
--0:Object
-----body:"Sed minima nemo fuga libero. Rerum incidunt odio voluptatem aut quidem consequuntur. Odio deserunt labore voluptatem quo aut atque nemo."
-----id:1
-----title:Object
-----updated_at:"1 tydzień temu"
-----user:"Ahmad Mills"
```

Comment: `this.questions.lenght` You have a typo, it should be `length`. Also, you might want to have a look at computed properties. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: @Cristy I try do this using documentation Boostrap Vue and I add: mounted() { this.totalRows = this.questions.length }, and still not working, have you idea why?

Comment: Either use `this.questions.length` where you need it, or use a computed property as mentioned above. If you set the length on mount, then it will be set to 0, as the API request was not sent yet.

Comment: @StanisławSzewczyk are you sure about this: `.then(res => this.questions = res.data.data)` ? Is the `res.data.data` actually where the questions array is?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `computed` property.
Check here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

It would look like below:

`template` (example)

```
<p>{{ totalRows }}</p>
```

`<script>`

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            questions: [],
            fields: [
                { key: 'id', label: 'ID', sortable: true },
                { key: 'title', label: 'Title', sortable: true },
                { key: 'updated_at', label: 'Last update', sortable: true},
            ],
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 5,
            pageOptions: [5, 10, 15]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        totalRows: function() {
             return this.questions.length
        },
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/api/question')
        .then(res => this.questions = res.data.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    },
}
```

---

A second option, just put the property in your template like:

```
{{ questions.length }}
```

But the `computed` property makes the template clearer and separate logic from visualization (this is the most valuable part in my opinion =) )

Answer (score -1):

Remember vue.js is a javascript framework so you can do all those things in vue that javascript can.

So `strings`, `arrays`, `objects` and `functions` etc all are used in the same way as in javascript.

So you can find length of string or array as `your_Array.length`

```
 axios.get('/api/question')
    .then(
           res => {
             this.questions = res.data.data
             //now you can get length using 
             questions.length 
             //or you can create a computed property
           }
     )
```

Read more about arrays [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)